# Php parse html dom and target elements

Tags: php, html, parsing, web, screen-scraping

I have a gaming server and i want to build a simple php to get my server players because there is no API to use

So after a little search i have found this [Simple php DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) And this is perfectly suitable for what i want to do :)

Lets say my server link contains this structure

```
<div id="server-page-info">

<div class="row-tight">
    <div class="box span1">
        <header>
            <h1>Players</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="box span1">
        <header>
            <h1>Ping</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-tight">
    <div class="box span1">
        <section class="box-content">
            <h5>
                0 / 64
            </h5>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="box span1">
        <section class="box-content">
            <h5>
                -ms
            </h5>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Lucky me, there are a bunch of *row-tight* and *box* and *box-content* class names :)

So i want to get the value of one of this *box-content* sections which is shows **0 / 64** above

**My php code**

Sorry im a newbie on PHP. you can also see how i have targeted the element but it does not work and i do not get anything :)

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = '';
$html = file_get_html($url);

$player = $html->find('div[id=server-page-info] .row-tight:nth-child(2) .box:first-child');

foreach( $player as $players ){

    echo $players->plaintext;

    }
```

I will also add one more question :) 
Now when i get the server players value as plaintext i want to wrap it in a div :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Simple html DOM manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) i don't see that it supports `nth-child`, but it supports other syntax: `$html->find('<element>', <nth-child>)`.So your code should look something like this:

`$player = $html->find('div[id=server-page-info]')->find('.row-tight',1)->find('.box',0);`

And i suggest to use `#` for ids instead of attributes:

`$player = $html->find('#server-page-info')->find('.row-tight',1)->find('.box',0);`

**UPDATE**

If you want to do next `find` you need always select only one element with `find('<element>', <nth-child>)` In your case: `$player = $html->find('#server-page-info',0)->find('.row-tight',1)->find('.box',0);` .

I have tested piece below and it displays 0 / 64.

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = str_get_html('<div id="server-page-info">
<div class="row-tight">
    <div class="box span1">
        <header>
            <h1>Players</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="box span1">
        <header>
            <h1>Ping</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-tight">
    <div class="box span1">
        <section class="box-content">
            <h5>
                0 / 64
            </h5>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="box span1">
        <section class="box-content">
            <h5>
                -ms
            </h5>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
</div>');
$player = $html->find('#server-page-info',0)->find('.row-tight',1)->find('.box',0);
echo $player->plaintext;
```